# JqueryUI Autocomplete prevent close on click outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Is there a solution to prevent hidding search results after an outside click? I have a long-running ajax request and don't want to sit and wait untill it is finished. It has to work in background and close results on ESC key is pressed or on one of the results is selected, but if I click outside, the autocomplete even doesn't show the result.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work properly:

```
...
    close : function (event, ui) {
        if ($("ul.ui-autocomplete, .ui-widget-content").filter(':hidden').length>0 && event.keyCode !== $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE) {
            $("ul.ui-autocomplete, .ui-widget-content").filter(':hidden').show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: try `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` doesn't work